# Greater-than sign throws error in ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

I have a very simple angularjs-code:

```
<div ng-hide="foo > 0" >xxxxxxxxx</div>
```

Returns the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[ng-hide='foo
bc.error @ browserLink:37
bh @ browserLink:37bp
...
```

foo is a number with a integer,I have checked this.

same error with:

```
<div ng-hide="1 > 0" >xxxxxxxxx</div>
```

but no errors with:

```
<div ng-hide="foo == 0" >xxxxxxxxx</div>
<div ng-hide="1 == 0" >xxxxxxxxx</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `<div ng-hide="foo &gt; 0" >xxxxxxxxx</div>`. Angular (or most probably the HTML parser) probably thinks the `>` is closing the element (and is strictly speaking disallowed there).

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I deactivate browserlink in VS, -->no errors